# Can Express 5 middleware use async/await?

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

```
async function unzipMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  const unzippedFiles = await unzipfile(req);
  req.files = unzippedFiles
}
```

```
app.post('import', unzipMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  // do something..
})
```

Is async / await possible in middleware with Express 5?

Comment: yea. just call `next()` to continue

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

```
async function unzipMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  const unzippedFiles = await unzipfile(req);
  req.files = unzippedFiles
  next();
}
```

***Middleware functions*** are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next middleware function in the application’s request-response cycle. The next middleware function is commonly denoted by a variable named *next*.